# Aligning columns of multiple tables, using CSS (or with help of minimal JS)?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Not sure if anyone has successfully achieved this. By using CSS (and minimal JS if required), can you make the relative columns of multiple tables to have the same width?

```html
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Class</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<div>Some text and elements here</div>

<table id="table2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Logic</td>
      <td>Tony</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>98</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Logic</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>More text here</p>

<table id="table3">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Maths</td>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maths</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>65</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <p>text here</p>
    <table id="table4">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="class" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="age" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="score" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

If I want the width of first, second, third and fourth columns across `table#table1`, `table#table2`, `table#table3` and `table#table4` to match relatively, what is the best way of doing it? (So all the first column has the same width; all the second column has the same width; and so on... )

I see that the only solution is to give fixed widths to the columns (or percentage ratios). *However*, I am looking for a non-width-specifying solution which allows the tables to adjust automatically accordingly to the content, like `table`'s default behaviour in browsers.

Another thing is... I want it to be backward compatible with older browsers, like IE9, so I guess no CSS Flex or Grid layouts should be used. Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried jquery's `width` method to get the width of Table1 and set it to the others?!

Comment: Thanks, but yes, I have tried that before, but I don't think it's that easy. Imagine 100% width tables, same column across different tables may have different widths... and it can be hard to decide how much width ratio to distribute across different tables, since different columns taking different widths may have different reasons behind: minimum of content width? spare width evenly distributed? word-wraping behaviour in content?

Comment: I suspect the only way that the width of a column in one table can actively match the varying width of a column in a completely separate table is by (somehow) "knowing" about it - which requires javascript.